# Generate html for a WSDL to test the api?

Tags: html, web-services

Is there any tool that can read a WSDL file and based on the input message definition, generate a html page which can be used to specify the inputs and invoke the apis. I do not have many complex types in the input message.

I need this to build some test UI for a service.

If I cant convert whole WSDL, an XSD parser which creates the html tags would be great

Thanks
Arvind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any tool to create a HTML page, but if you want to test WSDL / SOAP web services, I'd recommend [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org). They have a free and a PRO version, and even the free one is already really quite good and useful!

Marc

Comment: My service is not using SOAP but an internal framework, but the WSDL is the same. If I can use the xsd to generate html it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

a good option for readonly documentation purposes is: http://tomi.vanek.sk/index.php?page=wsdl-viewer